# Adding a new Angular Dependancy

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, treeview

I'm new to angular and I think I'm doing this right but I'm not sure. I just got pushed into a project without much help and I'm trying to figure this out. I need to make some data using a tree view. The old code was using ng-repeat so I need to do something like that. I found a library that can help with that called treeRepeat. I have 0 experience using npm or bower so I just downloaded "module.js" and "tree-repeat.js" and added it to the project and then added it to a bundle and called it in my html page but I get a error injecting module error and I can't figure out why.

I have the error link at bottom but its a huge link and I have no idea on how to hyperlink it.

App.js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['angularFileUpload', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.mask', 'ui.select', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls', 'angular.filter', 'smart-table', 'colorpicker.module', 'sf.treeRepeat'])
    .config(function ($httpProvider) {
        //make delete type json to facilitate passing object
        //to our generic method.
        $httpProvider.defaults.headers["delete"] = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'
        };
    });
```

EDIT: New error when I changed the bundle order. It now goes jquery first, treerepeat, and then angularjs.

https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod?p0=sf.treeRepeat

Calling code:

```
<div class="row">
      <ul>
         <li sf-treepeat="role in vm.roles">
             {{role.RoleName}}
             <ul>
                <li sf-treecurse></li>
             </ul>
         </li>
     </ul>
```

Bundle Order (The 2 files I added with tree-repeat are at the end of the angularjs bundle:

@section scripts {

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/manageUser")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angularjs")

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
    });

</script>
```

}

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: Why are you adding an object to the headers, they are supposed to be key/pair of value types.

Comment: you must include tree-repeat.js before App.js in your Html

Comment: @ElenaDBA I edited it in. CallumLinington I have no idea. This was before me. Mostafa That fixed that error but now I get another error.

Comment: 1.post your calling order under head tag. 2.post you jQuery code that using sf.treeRepeat.

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas Done.

Comment: try - https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/nomod

Comment: @ItsikMauyhas I checked the spelling and it's called in a script tag. Also it's already doing the less common fix.